# I need to replace flex gap which doesn't work in safari

Tags: html, css

I need to rewrite flex gap for safari.
i have 1 block and inside this block i put 3 input elements

[input][input][input]

and when i use this:

```
.myDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.myDiv > * + *  { 
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I have this:

[input][input]_____[input]

But i want this:

[input]____[input]_____[input]

If anyone knows a way to do this without losing height?

Because when I added it and it got a change in the position in height.

```
.inline-inputs > * * {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `justify-content: center` modifier.